# Table relations with Rails + React

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

My Users table (has many :`tweets`) has following columns:
`id`, `user_name`, `email`, `password`, `created_at`, `update_at`.

and my Tweets table (belongs to :`user`) has following columns:
`id`, `user_id`, `tweet`, `create_at`, `update_at`.

Now I'm making a React project that looks like:

```
import React from 'react'

class Tweet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tweet: this.props.tweet
    };
  }
  render() {
    const tweet = this.state.tweet;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{tweet.user_id}　{tweet.created_at}</p>
        <p>{tweet.tweet}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tweet;
```

Is there a way to write a code so I can get the `user_name` via `user_id`? I've tried `{tweet.user_id.user_name}` but it doesn't work or do I have to have a `user_name` column in Tweets table so `{tweet.user_name}` would be my best answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by including users information in my API like so:

```
def index
  tweets = Tweet.all.where(user_id: current_user.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: tweets.to_json(:include => :user) }
  end
end
```

This way I can get the user_name within my React component with `{tweet.user.user_name}`.

Comment: if you're showing only current_user tweets then its fine. If not, there are other ways to show tweets with corresponding user_name.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend adding another user_name column to the table because its bad database design since you already have the user_id and can lookup user info from based on that id.

Option #1:
I don't know what your parent component looks like calling your Tweet component, but if it has access to the user_name then i would pass it down along with the Tweet data via `<Tweet tweet={someTweet} username={someUser}>`.

Option #2:
After you pull your Tweet data, perform another request to get the user_name of all Tweets based on the tweet's user id. Add this user_name to the shape of the Tweet object in React, then your Tweet component will have access to the user_name via `tweet.user_name` and you don't need to change your Tweet table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I should go with the option #2, however, I am super new to React (+ I'm not a native English speaker) and it's hard to comprehend your advise... Would that be possible for you to write a sample code for me?

Comment: Sorry im not sure i can help more without seeing more of your code. For option #2, find where you get the data from your server to put in <Tweet tweet={someTweet}> and add another request to your server which sends your tweet's user ids and returns user_name's for each id. Maybe it will return pairs like {user_id, user_name}. Now you can add in the someTweet.user_name variable for all tweet objects.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I figured out myself in a different way after all (solution posted), but your advise was really meaningful and it should help others like me. I'll try your way one day when I'm more familiar with React.